# Angular shadowed this pointer

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js

Upgrading Angular broke some of my code. Previously the following statement worked:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './some.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./some.component.scss']
})
export class SomeComponent {
  ...
  public someMethod(): void {
    const defs = this.svg.select(function() {return this.parentNode; })
      .append('defs');
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Now this will throw the following two error messages:

> 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.
> An outer value of 'this' is shadowed by this container.

What is the correct replacement for this line?

Comment: Is parentNode in SomeComponent?

Comment: No. Its the parent of 'svg' (a d3js selection)

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this particular problem was actually multifaceted:

- Upgrading the used ES version
- Upgrading D3js

The statment can be translated to:

```
this.svg.select(function(this:any) {return this.parentNode;})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an ES5 arrow function instead. Arrow functions don't clobber or override `this`.

```js
  public someMethod(): void {
    const defs = this.svg.select(() => this.parentNode)
      .append('defs');
    ...
  }
```

If that doesn't fix it, use another variable to return from the function scope:

```js
  public someMethod(): void {
    const myParentNode = this.parentNode;
    const defs = this.svg.select(() => myParentNode)
      .append('defs');
    ...
  }
```

Comment: The solution was actually to use something like the following: this.svg.select(function(this:any) {return this.parentNode;})

Answer (score 0):

```js
 public someMethod(): void {
    const myParentNode = this.parentNode;
    const defs = this.svg.select(myParentNode)
      .append('defs');
  }
```

or much easier

```js
 public someMethod(): void {
    d3.select('svg')
      .append('defs');
  }
```